# how to pass softcoded element to crm web resource script

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm having trouble passing in the name of an element into a Dyanamics CRM web Resource javacript.

This code works:

```
function OnFormLoad()
    {
        var subGrid = window.parent.document.getElementById("Claims")
        // do work 
    }
```

This code doesn't:

```
function OnFormLoad(GridName)
    {
        var subGrid = window.parent.document.getElementById(GridName)
        // do work 
    }
```

How do I pass in the name of the element I want to work with?

Comment: Where is your CRM Web Resource? Embedded into a CRM Form?

Comment: "Where is your CRM Web Resource? Embedded into a CRM Form?" - yes, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please refrain from using document.getElementById in Dynamics as it is not supported.**

I believe you are trying to get GridContext and get Data from that Grid.

For Example on Account entity we have Contacts as Grid and then you wish to get data from that Grid.

I replicated the same on Account Entity (OnLoad) and get tried to get data from Contacts Grid.

When adding OnLoad event I have passed Grid name as Parameter as below.

[image]

I have added below onLoad Js on Account entity and was able to retrieve data from grid.

Note: I have added timeout because directly firing onload was not able to load complete page and then grid Name was not available.

```
function onLoad(executionContext,gridName){

setTimeout(function(){ getGridDatat(executionContext,gridName); }, 3000);


}

function getGridDatat(executionContext,gridName){
    debugger
var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

    var gridContext = formContext.getControl("Contacts"); // get the grid context
    var myRows = gridContext.getGrid().getRows();
/*var myRow = myRows.get(arg);
var gridRowData = myRow.getData();*/
var firstRow =myRows.get(0).getData();
    var firstRowAllAttributes = firstrow.entity.attributes.getAll()

    var firstRowfirstAttributeValue = firstrow.entity.attributes.get(0).getValue()

}
```

If you want to perform some operation on change of data formGird then there is one more way to achieve this. Make your grid as Editable and then you can find Events for that gird as below and could perform your operations.

[image]